# Cannot access to my web server out of campus?

Tags: apache-2.2

I cannot access to my web server out of campus.
I use EasyPHP (the lates version; all Apache and that kind of stuff is the latest version)
I configured httpd.conf to `Listen 9999` also I've tried `Listen 80`, I can access my server within the campus but not from outside. Why is that? And is it possible to do something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chances are real good that your campus is blocking such access at the perimeter firewall. I know we do. If that is the case, work with your IT department to identify who manages your perimeter security and what procedures need to be followed to allow off-campus access to your server.

Comment: Probably they won't help me. Can I workaround by using https, or a domain name that I've pointed it to my IP?

Comment: @ilhan Unlikely in the extreme. If their firewall is like ours, your IP address simply can't be reached from the outside by any means. You'll have to work with them to get off-campus visibility.

Comment: @ilhan - Without having quite a bit more detail, probably is going to be all that we can give you. If you don't manage your edge devices, then there is no way you can give us the info we need to give you a definitive answer. @sysadmin is most likely right, though.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you are using a machine that you control and putting a web server on it.

There are two probably reasons, technically, why your server cannot be accessed.

1. As mentioned in another answer, your college's firewall blocks it. In which case you will need to talk to the campus IT Department.
2. Your IP address is not routable off-campus. Is your IP address in the 10.x.x.x or 192.x.x.x range? If this is the case you have a larger problem -- you would need to have the department apply NAT (Network Address Translation) so that it would be routable outside.

Your IT folks may be able to do 1, but I doubt they will do 2 for you.

Are there other students on campus who have websites accessible from outside?

Comment: My "global" IP is 144.122.124.1xx (it is static, and unique to me) here is the full address: http://goo.gl/ayVI (also, if you look at the "Host of my IP" you will see domain name with subs, it is not my job, it says pc-100.dormitory2.dormitories). I don't think that there are other students that have web servers, I don't know. By the I've installed the server to my laptop.

Comment: By the way* I've installed the server to my laptop

Comment: Yes, then it is being blocked by the Firewall. Also, your DNS name is internal to your school only. You definitely have to work with campus IT.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s an explanation of the policy on your campus that restricts outside access:

http://cisn.odtu.edu.tr/2007-13/ag_guvenligi.php